# How to open new page in browser from java web application running on tomcat?

Tags: java, x11

I have a java web application deployed on a virtual machine with tomcat and without X11 server.

In this application I try to open a web page in the client browser (a oauth2 login page) with the JAVA command:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI)
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

> No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an
> operation which requires it.

I have already tried to solve by installing X11 and setting the `DISPLAY` variable on the server, but it didn't help.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why does it require x11 on a server side?

Comment: @AlexeyR. I don't know

Comment: Probable that is the actual issue you need to solve.

Comment: what error you get after installing X11